# unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_regex.Pattern' and 'str'

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I get the following URL when trying to match a URL with regex. How do I solve this error. Im trying to extract the text from href using regex and append it to the original URL .Something like a redirection. I cant post the URL as it is not authorized.

Example URL is abc.com

Im parsing the above URL to extract a href text from a dropdown menu,say the the text is `<li><a href="ABC.asp?DER=PI">Myshop</a></li>`

Im extracting data from  inside the a href and making the URL as abc.com/ABC.asp?DER=PI

I get the following URL when trying to match a URL with regex and concatenate with a URL string. How do I solve this error

`a=(re.compile('href=(.+Home\.asp\?Pipe=.+)\"'))`

I get the following Error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-189-01866482c481> in <module>
     10 for item in data1:
     11     a=(re.compile('href=(.+Home\.asp\?Pipe=.+)\"'))
---> 12     print(a + url)
     13 #print(data2)
     14 #for item in data

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_regex.Pattern' and 'str'
```

Comment: @ParthS007 Whats the problem ? This question has not been answered in StackOverflow previously

Comment: You tried to add a regex object to a `str` object (of course it will error). What did you expect to happen, what are you trying to acheive? Did you mean to do `print(a.search(url))` or something like that? (Maybe `a.match(url)`)?

Comment: I edited the post .Please check and let me know

Comment: How does `Some text (XXX)` play into `abc.com/ABC.asp?DER=PI`? I.e. how did `abc.com` turn into `abc.com/ABC.asp?DER=PI`?

Comment: Thats what Im trying to achieve by using regex. I used BS4 to arrive until abc.com/ABC.asp?DER=PI? ,Now Im trying to  concatenate with URL so arrive final URL which is abc.com/ABC.asp?DER=PI?. To make it more clear  abc.com/ABC.asp?DER=PI? is a text in a href tag which Im trying to extract.Does that answer your question @Error-SyntacticalRemorse

Answer (score 1):

`re.compile` compiles a regexp pattern into a regular expression object, which can be used for matching using its match() and search() methods only.

You can't add a regexp object with the string.

Please read https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html for more info.

I hope it helps

Comment: How do i solve this error then?What should I do? Im new to regex and find it a bit difficult to understand

Comment: Can you please add more details about what you are trying to achieve by this so that I can add the response in answer. Thanks

Comment: Im trying to extract text in href since its a redirecting URL to append to a URL and do some more computations on that

Comment: Can you please tell the value of `a` of any item?

Comment: I did follow some regex tutorial .Thats how I got the regex. But concatenating gives me issues

Comment: @Akshay  Its more a matter of if you did research (i.e. a tutorial) on regex you would see your error and easily fix it.  The downvote for questions explicitly says: "This question does not show any research effort...". It appears when you say "... searched possible websites" that you just kept looking for your error (couldn't find a solution) and instead of taking the time to follow a full regex tutorial you decided to ask someone to solve it for you.  You grabed code from somewhere, it errored out, and you ask someone else to fix it for you instead of taking some time to follow a tutorial.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse : I dint grab code from anywhere. I cant post the code because its code from my school for a research project.FYI I did look through tutorials and couldnt understand stuff. As I said previously I spent 5 hours debugging that one error alone.I can paste a screenshot of my Jupyter Notebook except I dunno how to do that in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is extract the `href`:

```
import re
txt = '<li><a href="ABC.asp?DER=PI">Myshop</a></li>'
url = 'abc.com'
find_href = re.compile(r'href="(.+)"')
href = find_href.search(txt)
if href:
    print(f"{url}/{href.group(1)}")
```

Output:

```
abc.com/ABC.asp?DER=PI
```

Comment: Thankyou. I figured the solution by converting BeautifulSoup Obj into string after a day of troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

@akshay re.compile(pattern) => returns re object and you are trying to perform a concatination operation with string (i.e. url - not clear since complete code snippet is not provided) which is not allowed. Please provide complete code snippet and purpose of it, so that I can provide some better insight to it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Rishav I got  the error after 1 day of troubleshooting